# Does the name Jiraiya mean something that connects these 2 instances?

Tags: naruto, japanese-language, tales-of-phantasia

While I was playing *Tales of Phantasia*, in the Future where the vocal impressionists are (nearby to where the Elven Forest is) there is a guy dressed up like a frog. When you talk to him he says (according to the English translation)

> Ninja Art!
>   Jiraiya!
>   Ribbit?

Obviously this made me think of Jiraiya from *Naruto* and his affinity with frogs and to my understanding *Tales of Phantasia* predates *Naruto*.

So does the name Jiraiya mean something that connects what this frog guy says in *Tales of Phantasia* and Jiraiya in *Naruto*?

Comment: [Jiraiya](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jiraiya) is a common folklore.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This originates from the Japanese folklore [児雷也豪傑物語](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jiraiya), The Tale of the Gallant Jiraiya

> In the legend, Jiraiya is a ninja who uses shapeshifting magic to morph into a gigantic toad. As the heir of a powerful clan in Kyūshū of the same name, Jiraiya fell in love with Tsunade (綱手), a beautiful young maiden who has mastered slug magic. His arch-enemy was his one-time follower Yashagorō (夜叉五郎), later known as Orochimaru (大蛇丸), a master of serpent magic (the kanji 大蛇 literally means "giant snake" or "serpent"). It was first recorded in 1806 - [classic tale](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jiraiya#Classic_tale)

Series such as Naruto, and Tales of Phantasia draw inspiration of this story in their elements, and also naming. All though in the Tales series it is more of a hidden reference. In Naruto almost the whole story is played out through the legendary three.

> In Naruto, a popular manga and anime television series, Jiraiya appears in the series as a ninja with the ability to summon giant toads. Along with the series' versions of Tsunade and Orochimaru, he is part of a trio of legendary ninja known as the Densetsu no Sannin ("Legendary Three Ninja"). One of the anime's episodes is titled "The Tale of Jiraiya the Gallant."

Jiraiya is also a known element in the series

- [Gintama](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gin_Tama): Where Jiraia is the strongest ninja of the Oniwanbanshu
- [Karasu Tengu Kabuto](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karasu_Tengu_Kabuto)
- [and several more](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jiraiya#In_popular_culture)